# What is the space in between flights of stairs where you can see all the way down called?

Tags: slang, technical

The space between flights of stairs that is kinda like a tunnel of sorts. Or a shaft. Does it have a name? It needs a name. Maybe this should be posted on a architecture page.

Comment: Lightwell if there is a roof window above,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are referring to 
***[stairwell](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/stairwell)***:

​

> a long, vertical passage through a building around which a set of stairs is built.

[image]

(Cambridge Dictionary)

The idea of “shaft” has been commonly referred to as “well” referring to stairs from about [mid-1800.](https://www.etymonline.com/word/stairwell)

Comment: This is not quite correct. A stairwell is bounded by the exterior of the stairs, not the interior; it includes the space taken by the stairs themselves. If there's another word for the interior space, I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: @Xerxes - it is still a stairwell. If you fall down a stairwell, that’s the shaft you are falling in.

Comment: Not all stairwells have an open space like this. Sometimes there are flights in alternating directions with a very narrow gap between them, and sometimes that gap is filled by a wall. Still, I would probably use the word "stairwell" when describing the middle part of this picture.

Answer (score 2):

The gap in the middle is called a "Well-hole".

> a. An opening through a floor or series of floors, esp. one into which a staircase, chimney stack, etc., may be installed, or one which admits light
> b. A central open space forming the vertical core around which the stairs of a winding or spiral staircase may be set.
>
> OED

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've added corroboration here. Richard: welcome to ELU. Please take a note of the help on good answers. It doesn't have to be OED: any *reputable* corroboration should be acceptable.